# Putting more content further down my website

Tags: html, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, web

So, I am a beginner in web development and i am curretly making a website of a hypothetical travel start up, so i have the home page/landing page up but i don't know how to add content down on my website, basically i want the content when i scroll down, basically like i want a fresh slate where i can put more of my content, i don't know how to explain but like when we visit a website we see a screen with the home page and then we scroll down to reveal more content i want just that, i am linking the home page that i made and also the css, please help me with this.

P.S:- When you run this on html you can even see the text "The Various Tours we do" which was supposed to be down in my website in a new fresh screen rather than on that same page where i have the logo and everything.

Start-Up html code:-

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: url(https://i.pinimg.com/originals/e5/5c/e0/e55ce0b3aa7f8f1c520516dae8f691bf.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#content {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 25%;
}

html {
  height: 100%
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Gloss And Bloom Regular';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  src: local('Gloss And Bloom Regular'), url('Gloss_And_Bloom.woff') format('woff');
}

h1 {
  font-family: 'Gloss And Bloom Regular';
  font-size: 7em;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: 0px 4px 3px orange;
}

h3 {
  font-family: 'Satisfy', cursive;
  color: white
}

hr {
  border: 0;
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn 3s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

#fade-in {
  animation: fadeIn 2s;
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

.navbar-brand:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: white;
}

#secondPage {
  text-align: center;
  height: relative;
  float: bottom;
  color: black;
}

#heading {
  float: top;
  margin: 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<title>Wishy Travels</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Satisfy&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Wishy</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item active">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Sign Up </a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link active" href="#">Login</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>



<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div id="content">
        <h1 class='fade-in'> Wishy Travels </h1>
        <h3 id="fade-in">Don't listen to what they say, GO SEE.</h3>
        <hr>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light">EXPLORE!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="secondPage">
  <h2>
    <center>THE VARIOUS TOURS WE DO</center>
  </h2>
</div>

<div id="heading">
  The Various Tours we do!
</div>





<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
```

Comment: Adding content when scrolling down to avoid long render times is a bit old fashioned. Have a look at the [new possibilities of CSS](https://web.dev/content-visibility/) to accomplish this in another way.

Comment: It's not rendering that i am after, i just want to know how to place my content down under the image that i've used as a background or let's just say the home page, i want the user to scroll down to get more content.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways of handling nav based on the framework you use. However, assuming you are using static HTML files...

Create a separate file for each page and update your `<a>` tags to link to them. Then place the content for each page in each file

File Structure:

- index.html (default landing page)
- about.html
- services.html

  Within your html:

  ```
    <a href="/about.html">About Page</a>

    <a href="/services.html">Our Services</a>
  ```

Comment: so after reading your question again I see this is not what you are after

Comment: I know how to link pages what i want is the content to be down like the first thing that the user sees is the background that i've used and the home page then i want the user to scroll down for futher content, what i am not getting is how to place the content down, like imagine like this this home page that i've made now i want a fresh slate when the user scrolls down a fresh slate to put more content.

Comment: have a look at my other answer, perhaps that will help

Answer (score 0):

OK, so perhaps my first answer was more relevant. If you want a full screen landing section use viewport height setting (vh) to have it take 100% of the viewport. You could also combine this with with css scroll snapping to ensure when the user scrolls down, the landing content fully leaves view.

https://codepen.io/Ma3147/pen/oNzwJNP

```
<div class='root'>
   <div class='landing-content'>
      <h1> Landing Page</h1>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class='rest-content'>
      <h2>More Content</h2>
      <p>
         Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </p>
   </div>
</div>

.root{
   scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
}
.landing-content{
   width: 100%;
   height: 100vh;
   background: red;
}
.rest-content{
   scroll-snap-align: start;
   background: blue;
   color: white;
   min-height: 100vh;
}
h2 {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/introducing-css-scroll-snap-points/

https://codepen.io/Ma3147/pen/oNzwJNP